# How can i get the 2nd row for all users

Tags: sql-server

I have a TempTable that has the table setup Empname SwipeTime and description, shown below

```
Mike 2019-05-17 12:00:16.383 User Granted Exit From Door Using Reading Device 
Mike 2019-05-17 12:36:11.753 User Granted Entry To Door Using Reading Device
John 2019-05-17 12:00:16.383 User Granted Exit From Door Using Reading Device 
John 2019-05-17 12:36:11.753 User Granted Entry To Door Using Reading Device
Steve 2019-05-17 12:00:16.383 User Granted Exit From Door Using Reading Device 
Steve 2019-05-17 12:36:11.753 User Granted Entry To Door Using Reading Device
```

how can i grab the newest record for each employee while all have different swipe time and descriptions.

```
SELECT Distinct
    MAX(EmployeeName) AS EmployeeName,
    MAX(SwipeTime) AS MaxSwipeTime,
    Description
FROM #WhosInOut
GROUP BY EmployeeName,Description, SwipeTime
ORDER BY  EmployeeName, MAX(SwipeTime) ;
```

i would like to have a list of all users with just the newest record not both whether its exit or entry

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `row_number()` :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by employeename order by swipetime desc) as seq
      from #WhosInOut t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a sub-query:

```
SELECT a.*, b.Description
FROM
    (SELECT Distinct
        EmployeeName EmployeeName,
        MAX(SwipeTime) AS MaxSwipeTime  
     FROM #WhosInOut
     GROUP BY 1)a
JOIN #WhosInOut b
 ON a.EmployeeName = b.EmployeeName and a.MaxSwipeTime = b.SwipeTime
ORDER by EmployeeName, MaxSwipeTime
```

Answer (score 0):

Optionally a correlated subquery will work:

```
SELECT EmployeeName, SwipeTime, Description
FROM #WhosInOut t1
WHERE SwipeTime = (SELECT MAX(SwipeTime) FROM #WhosInOut WHERE t1.EmployeeName = EmployeeName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a row_number function to extract the most recent as such:

```
select x.empname, x.swipetime, x.description
from (
select a.empname, a.swipetime, a.description, ROW_NUMBER() (over partition by a.empname order by a.swipetime desc) as Ranks
from #whosinout a) x
where ranks = 1
```